# How to fix GCP firewall rules are not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firewall, google-vpc

I have a `network` in `GCP` with configured firewall rules. I have couple of instances and two of them are as below.

```
instance 1 - with network tag "kube-master"
instance 2 - with network tag "kube-minion"
```

And I want to ping from `kube-master` to `kube-minion` So, I set up a firewall rule (`master-to-node`) for `icmp` as below.

[image]

But the problem is I can't still ping from `kube-master` to `kube-minion`. I logged into instance 1 (`kube-master`) and tried to ping the public ip address of instance 2 (`kube-minion`) but it **doesn't ping**

As above image, am I restricting this behaviour? But I have setup the priority as `2` so it will take the precedence.

When I set `source` as `0.0.0.0/0` instead of giving `kube-master` it works, but I need to only do this (send traffic to `kube-minion`) only from `kube-master`

Can someone tell me where am I doing the mistake? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags)

> Thus, the network tags are still only meaningful in the network to which the instance's network interface is attached.

Therefore, if you access to the VM with the Public IP, you are going out of your network to reach it, and the tag information is lost. Use the private IP of the VM and it will work as expected.

Add 0.0.0.0/0 as source, or the public IP of the master in /32 (better) if you want to continue to use the instance 2 public IP

Answer (score 0):

Source tags only apply to traffic sent from the network interface of another applicable instance in your VPC network. A source tag cannot control packets whose sources are external IP addresses, even if the external IP addresses belong to instances.

When you ping from `instance-1` the external IP address of `instance-2`, the ICMP request is translated and therefore on the receiving side, the request appears to come from an IP address(external IP of instance-1) that is not associated with the network tag `kube-master`.

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Would you care to explain the diagram as well?

Comment: @JananathBanuka, Sure. You can also trace these hops yourself, using the [connectivity test](https://console.cloud.google.com/net-intelligence/connectivity) in your own project. Here I am showcasing what happens when you ping from `instance-1`, the external IP address of `instance-2`: 1. the ICMP request is allowed by the default egress FW; 2. The routing table determines that the request must be translated, hence the destination belongs to a different subnet; 3. Finally the public IP of instance-2 is reached so a translation from external to internal is needed

Comment: ...4. The packet is dropped, because no rule is hit, except for the one that drops everything(the rule that you created, allowing ingress with source `kube-master` is not hit because in this specific step, the source is an external IP address and this is not correlated with instance-1)